# httpClient can not handle ipv6 cookies

Tags: java, session, cookies, httpclient, ipv6

I use httpClient 4.5 with java. I want to send http GET/POST with "CloseableHttpClient" class.

```
 BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSF).setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();
 //.......
 //.......
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(protocol+"://"+ip+"/");
          CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Actually it works with ipv4. But when it comes to ipv6, it apears can not keep the session ID alive.
I have printed out the session ID to check.
In ipv4 the session ID could be sent out correctly as following.

> Cookie: SID=mdplxtedrjokwhxj

However the same code can not work with ipv6, are there difference between ipv4 and ipv6?

Or is this a current limitation in httpClient 4.5?

Comment: Your cookies are an application feature that has nothing to do with the network protocol.

Comment: Thanks, however I use "java apache httpClient library" on both ipv6 and ipv4. Ipv4 works fine but ipv6 does not work.

Comment: That doesn't mean that either IPv4 or IPv6 know anything about cookies; they don't. Cookies have nothing to do with the network protocol.